# Java File .write() a stream of integers

Tags: java, file, file-io

I run this code, I get "File written !" and when I open the file to see it, every thing that is written is not making any sense. You can understand that I want to write 012345678910 in the file. Is there any other way to write in file than `buffW.write(k);`. Are there any other mistakes I made?

```
package thema4_create_write_read_file;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;

public class FW {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File newFile = new File("newFile.txt");
        if (newFile.exists()) {
            System.out.println("The file already exists");
        } else {
            try {
                newFile.createNewFile();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                FileWriter fileW = new FileWriter(newFile);
                BufferedWriter buffW = new BufferedWriter(fileW);
                for (int k = 0; k <= 10; k++) {
                    buffW.write(k); // This is where the problem occurs
                }
                buffW.close();
                System.out.print("File written !");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way of writing (k) as integer and not as string ,in order to read it as int then?

Comment: You are seeing the character representations of those integer values, see [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart).

Comment: Your code has many issues. You are catching Exception. You are not using finally. If I were your prof you would have some issues passing the class ;)

Answer (score 4):

[Bufferedwriter#write(int c)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write(int)):

> Writes a single character.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> c - int specifying a character to be written

Use [Writer#write(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write(java.lang.String))

```
writer.write(String.valueOf(integer));
```

Comment: yea this is a better solution

Comment: That is better . Thank you. That's one a the reasons i don't like java.I am studying for exams next week.

Answer (score 1):

`BufferedWriter#write(int i)` writes character that corresponds to `i` in [Unicode Table](http://unicode-table.com/en/) you can take a look what will be written by using

```
System.out.print((char)k);
```

Now if you want to write int value of `k` you should probably use `PrintWriter`

```
PrintWriter printW = new PrintWriter(fileW);
printW.print(k);
```

You can also take a look at `PrintStream#print()` method (`System.out` is instance of PrintStream) but Writers are preferred over Streams for character I/O operations.

Comment: @TheNewIdiot Thanks, you are right, but I could swear that it worked with `write()`. My bad.